# my android studio crashes when i convert string into int

Tags: java, android

So I'm making a tinder like app I'm doing a coin system in which a user has 20 coins by default and after he swipes right 1 coin will be added to the total, I'm using an edittext to show the coins amount , I read articles on how to convert string to int but it doesn't seem to help and the app crashes after I do what most articles say I need to do, this is some of my code and thanks !

```
private DatabaseReference usersDb;


ListView listView;
List<cards> rowItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mCoins = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.coins);
    String myEditValue = mCoins.getText().toString();
    final int myEditNum = Integer.parseInt(myEditValue);

    usersDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    checkUserSex();

    rowItems = new ArrayList<cards>();

    arrayAdapter = new arrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item, rowItems );

    SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.frame);

    flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    flingContainer.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
        @Override
        public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
            Log.d("LIST", "removed object!");
            rowItems.remove(0);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {

            cards obj = (cards) dataObject;
            String userId = obj.getUserId();
            usersDb.child(userId).child("connections").child("nope").child(currentUId).setValue(true);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        @Override
        public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {
            cards obj = (cards) dataObject;
            String userId = obj.getUserId();
            usersDb.child(userId).child("connections").child("yeps").child(currentUId).setValue(true);
            isConnectionMatch(userId);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            mCoins.setText(myEditNum+ "1");

        }
```

`

Comment: Post the crash logs too .

Comment: i'm using my phone as a testing tool for the apk i only get "The app has crashed"

Comment: Wohhhhh .. so you want us to guess the exception ?? Connect device to adb and get the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you are concatenating

```
myEditNum+ "1"
```

Move your string and int to onRightCardExit method, and make the sum:

```
String myEditValue = mCoins.getText().toString();
final int myEditNum = Integer.parseInt(myEditValue);
mCoins.setText(String.valueOf(myEditNum+1));
```